# For given rules, discard some rules by imposing conditions

Tags: list-manipulation, string-manipulation, code-request

For a given input, and after some implementing conditions I want to discard unnecessary rules and pick only relevant rules.

More explicitly, suppose I have a following transformation rules.

```
{{Subscript[p, i] -> Subscript[k, 2] + Subscript[k, 3] - Subscript[p, i],   Subscript[p, j] -> -Subscript[p, j]},{Subscript[p, i] -> -Subscript[k, 2] - Subscript[k, 3] - Subscript[p, i],  Subscript[p, j] -> -Subscript[p, j]}, {Subscript[p, i] -> -Subscript[p, i],   Subscript[p, j] ->  Subscript[k, 2] + Subscript[k, 3] - Subscript[p, j]}, {Subscript[p, i] -> Subscript[p, i],   Subscript[p, j] -> -Subscript[k, 2] - Subscript[k, 3] - Subscript[p, j]},Subscript[p, i] -> Subscript[p, i], Subscript[p, j] -> Subscript[p, j]}}
```

I want to pick the relevant rules out of these.

Specifically, I want to apply this transformation for the expressions

```
 aa=EPP[A[{i}, {1,2,3}],B[{j},{1,2}],CC[{i,j},{2,3}],A[{i,j},{1,2}]]
```

where $A[\{i\},\{1,2,3\}] = \pm (p_i - k_1 - k_2 -k_3)$, $B[\{j\},\{1,2\}]= \pm (p_{j} - k_{1} - k_{2})$, $CC[\{i,j\},\{2,3\}] = \pm(p_{i} + p_{j} - k_{2} - k_{3})$, Here for the functions, what matters is the relative sign of $p$ and $k$.  [For simplicity let me fix the $\pm$ to $+$]

Now applying for $A,B,CC$, and want to discard the rules that do not produce the criteria rule

Criteria rule in explicitly,

-(1)  After performing transformations, the $p_{i}, p_{j}$ have a same sign with its magnitude is $1$

-(2) After performing transformations, the $k_{1}, \cdots, k_{3}, \cdots$ have the same sign with its magnitude $1$

-(3) After performing transformations, the sign of $p$ and the sign of $k$ should be opposite.

---

Suppose I have a rules $\{p_{i} \rightarrow p_{i} - p_{j} +k_1, p_j \rightarrow p_{j}+k_1\}$.

Applying to $aa$, the above rule is not valid. First $A$ term produces $p_i - p_j -k_2 - k_3$ and from and it violates the condition (1), and for $CC$ it produces $p_i - p_j + 2 k_1 - k_2 -k_3$, so it violates the condition (1), (2), (3).

---

In a coded form what I want to make is

```
  Functionname[exp_, Rules_]
```

and it produces the relevant rules in a list format.

---

The followings are my Psuedo code

```
  Functionname[exp_EPP, Rules_List]:=Module[{EX,ELA,ELB,ELCC},
   (** Make the expression as List**)
  EX=List@@EPP;

   (** Select A,B,C, parts for the given expressions, Exp**)
  ELA=Select[EX,Head[#]==A &]; 
  ELB=Select[EX,Head[#]==B &]; 
  ELCC=Select[EX,Head[#]==CC &]; 

  LELA=Length[ELA];
  LELB=Length[ELB];
  LELCC=Length[ELCC];
  
  (** At this moment I have no idea for making Criterai function which have two inputs, the expressions, and Rules, and produce the correct rules. **)
  CA=Criteria@@@Table[{ELA[[ii]],Rules},{ii,LELA}];
  CB=Criteria@@@Table[{ELB[[ii]],Rules},{ii,LELB}];
  CC=Criteria@@@Table[{ELCC[[ii]],Rules},{ii,LELCC}];

  Intersection[CA,CB,CC]
  ]
```

How I can make Criteria, or is there any simple method for this?